# Solid discussion of language design -- covariant and contravariant types

Tags: types, variance

*By discussion I mean blog entry, book (preferably) or alike.*

### Background

I am reading for second time Scala Programming by Martin Odersky, Lex Spoon and Bill Venners and with great surprise I've read pieces about covariance and contravariance.

The reason I am posting this question is this -- the authors starts with building class Queue and discuss how, where, can and cannot covariance is used. Every step is logical result of preceding step, however one of the last step is adding element to queue (at front):

```
(elem : Apple) :: (queue[Orange])
```

However in Scala it works this way, that the result is queue with type Fruit.

And this is in my opinion wrong -- if someone would like queue of Fruits, it should be such queue in the first place. Changing type on-fly is too dynamic for my taste (i.e. it is like adding ints and strings, just to get `object` type).

Since mentioned book is about Scala, and variance of types is just a part of it, I am looking for something more substantial.

### The question

Thus **the question** -- what should I read about language design, focused on type variance? Could it be by any chance "Types and Programming Languages" by Benjamin C. Pierce (it is on my to-buy list)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Wikipedia for Covariance and Contravariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29) is somewhat helpful.  In general, covariance and contravariance are pretty cool factiods, and have some deep consequences in understanding programming languages, but I'm not sure how helpful it is to know about their inner workings as a programmer.  The pioneering work in this area was done by Liskov (famous for the Liskov substitution principle).  There's also a nice article by John Cook [that you can read!](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/07/19/covariance-and-contravariance/) There are a few cool academic papers that you might read, namely "A semantics of multiple inheritance" (Luca Cardelli, who also wrote a very good book that I haven't entirely read, "A Theory of Objects," covering similar things in the semantics object oriented languages.)  I believe the paper that first mentions co/contra-variance in programming languages is Liskov's own "A Behavioral Notion of Subtyping."  While I haven't read this in a while, the paper gives an account of the theory with respect to not just function types, but type predicates (and this giving a much more general description of how the type system works with these general principles).  Last, in case slides are your thing, Jeff Foster (and I, as the TA) are teaching a compilers course at UMD this semester, and he has some great [slides on type systems!](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2012/cmsc430/schedule.shtml)

To make a small comment, programming language design is a much, much bigger area than this variance you find.  If you start reading Ben Pierce's TAPL, you will easily be distracted by most other topics in the book, which are also good.  Co and contravariance are cool, but I think that there are many other equally cool things you'll find within programming language theory, and this strikes me as far from the most astonishing thing :-)

Comment: Thank you. I know that language does not end on variance of type, what I was looking for, is rather not theory but decisions in design given (even imaginary) language. For example in Scala authors discussed why they didn't make some collection covariant (because it is not immutable), and such discussion I am looking for.

Comment: As far as that goes, almost every discussion of this will be based on an extension of the lambda calculus with subtyping. That is sort of an imaginary language (in the sense that nobody actually uses it for real programming), and also easier to reason about than a nastier "real world" language (which usually doesn't have a formal definition).